# Crystal Reports Multi Select parameter - compare selected values with available values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a multi-select parameter `?Foobar` that is dynamically populated with a varying number of values.

Is there any way to determine both the total number of available values and the number of values selected by the user?

So if the list contained

```
A
B
C
```

and the user selected

```
B
C
```

I'd like to know that there were 3 available and 2 were selected.

I know that 2 were selected because I can interrogate `?Foobar`, but I do not know how to determine how many were available in the list
(that is, without populating a different parameter in the report with that count.)

Comment: Is the parameter single or dynamic cascading parameter

Comment: Siva it is a single parameter, it is not a cascading parameter

Comment: If its a single parameter you can use sql expression to extract count of that field from databse and display in report.